# My query isn't working properly, having time issue with the query itself

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Here is the query that is supposed to give me results for the last 12 months, but it is giving me the whole results since 2014.

What is wrong with it?

I tried doing

```
(where a.time > '2020-01-01 00:00:00')
```

but I do not want a fixed date in the query.

```
SET @no_of_months = 12; #change to the desired no. of months
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if NOT EXISTS newAuditlog
SELECT
a.id, a.user, a.action, a.project, a.info, a.TIME, a.project_ref, a.workpackage_ref, a.partner_ref
FROM auditlog a
WHERE a.time < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @no_of_months MONTH))
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user;
SELECT
na.id, na.user, b.roles, na.action, na.project, na.info, na.TIME, na.project_ref, na.workpackage_ref, na.partner_ref
FROM newAuditlog na
INNER JOIN(
SELECT u.id AS user_id,
u.username,
GROUP_CONCAT(r.role ORDER BY r.role SEPARATOR ', ') AS roles
FROM   user_has_role uhr
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON (uhr.user_id = u.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN role r ON (uhr.role_id = r.id)
GROUP  BY uhr.user_id
ORDER  BY uhr.user_id
)b
ON SUBSTR(na.user, INSTR(na.user, "(")+1, INSTR(na.user, ")") -1- (INSTR(na.user, "("))) = b.user_id;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE newAuditlog;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE a.time < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @no_of_months MONTH))`

you have `<`, but you want `>`

Comment: OMG! thank you so much... it was right

actually it is kinda dumb when i write such a code and get stacked for little tiny thing like the '<' or '>' sign

Comment: Honestly, it happens all the time to everybody